# How to seek/keyset pagination on alphabetical data

Tags: postgresql, pagination, keyset-pagination

- I have 2 tables

**resources**

[image]

**resource_votes_aggregate** which stores the number of likes per resource_id

[image]

- I want to **paginate through resources in descending order of their title** using seek/keyset pagination
- **Without Pagination**, this is what you get

[image]

- I want the results in batches of 5 as I am paginating 5 results at a time

My PAGE 1 query worked without issues using the query below

```
SELECT
   r.resource_id,
   title,
   COALESCE(likes, 0) AS likes 
FROM
   resources r 
   LEFT JOIN
      resource_votes_aggregate a 
      ON r.resource_id = a.resource_id 
WHERE
   category_id = 1 
ORDER BY
   title DESC,
   resource_id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

- How do I get the **next page** using **keyset/seek** pagination?

**My attempt**

```
SELECT
   r.resource_id,
   title,
   COALESCE(likes, 0) AS likes 
FROM
   resources r 
   LEFT JOIN
      resource_votes_aggregate a 
      ON r.resource_id = a.resource_id 
WHERE
   category_id = 1 
   AND 
   (
      likes,
      title
   )
   < (586, 'Zatoichi Meets Yojimbo (Zatôichi to Yôjinbô) (Zatôichi 20)') 
ORDER BY
   title DESC,
   resource_id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

**Incorrect Results**

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

I have created a [FIDDLE HER](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dNnrjBRei15oLUFBd6y1mV/0)E which loads 20 results? How to paginate this in batches of 5 using seek pagination?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that would do what you need:

`OFFSET n FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` and `sort_column > last_val`

Example 1:

```
SELECT
   r.resource_id,
   title,
   COALESCE(likes, 0) AS likes 
FROM
   resources r 
   LEFT JOIN
      resource_votes_aggregate a 
      ON r.resource_id = a.resource_id 
WHERE
   category_id = 1 
   AND 
   (
      likes,
      title
   )
   < (586, 'Zatoichi Meets Yojimbo (Zatôichi to Yôjinbô) (Zatôichi 20)') 
ORDER BY
   title DESC,
   resource_id DESC
OFFSET 5
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

You would then just change the OFFSET value each time.

Then the other way would be to keep track of the title and resource_id in your application layer, and then pass this to the query so that you start further down the result set:

```
SELECT
   r.resource_id,
   title,
   COALESCE(likes, 0) AS likes 
FROM
   resources r 
   LEFT JOIN
      resource_votes_aggregate a 
      ON r.resource_id = a.resource_id 
WHERE
   category_id = 1 
   AND 
   (
      likes,
      title
   )
   < (586, 'Zatoichi Meets Yojimbo (Zatôichi to Yôjinbô) (Zatôichi 20)')
   AND
     (title,resource_id) > (last_title_id_from_before,last_resource_id_from_before)
ORDER BY
   title DESC,
   resource_id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

This would ensure you skip rows from previous pages, but then downside with this strategy is you wouldn't have a way of going back a page again.

Comment: your solution does not work, i created a fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dNnrjBRei15oLUFBd6y1mV/0 to test it

Comment: The query you used there doesn't match the query you posted here, and doesn't use either solution I proposed.  I have adjusted your example to include of the solutions, and it's working for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dNnrjBRei15oLUFBd6y1mV/3

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: no this uses limit offset, seek pagination without a sequential scan is what i am looking for